# Are the advantages to uploading files in a form one at a time rather than all when the form is submitted?

Tags: forms, uploading, files

I have a form in my application where user can drop some files (images, csv, or other file types.)

My current flow is:

1. User drops the file
2. I read the File and show an preview
3. User Submit the form
4. I Upload the file to GCP (Google Cloud) and retrieve a file address
5. I save that address in the form

With this method I have the advantage of not polluting GCP with useless file (like user dragged file 1, user removed it then added file 2, with file 1 uploaded for no reason). But I might have to wait a slightly longer time when submitting the form.

I've seen online that most of the platform I use (like Jira/Shopify/Fb) that they upload the file as soon as you drag, and then when you submit they wait for the file, or they submit the form directly (since they have the link).

Is there any advantage (other than lower wait time) that I do not see by this second approach?